# Cat file find epochs and then convert the epochs to date

Tags: bash, date, epoch

i have a file with:

```
....1342477599376
    1342479596867
    1342480248580
    1342480501995
    1342481198309
    1342492256524
    1342506099378....
```

these lines `...` means Various character. I'd like to read this file with cat (it is essential that i need to with that) and get these lines with sed commands, than i'd like to convert the epoch to date...

```
cat myfile.log  | sed '...*//' | sed 's/...*//' | date -d @$1
```

Unfortunately this isn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, using `sed`:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/^.*\([0-9]\{13\}\).*/date -d @\1/" | sh
```

Results:

```
Thu Jun  4 14:16:16 EST 44511
Sat Jun 27 17:07:47 EST 44511
Sun Jul  5 06:09:40 EST 44511
Wed Jul  8 04:33:15 EST 44511
Thu Jul 16 05:58:29 EST 44511
Sat Nov 21 05:42:04 EST 44511
Fri Apr 29 10:56:18 EST 44512
```

HTH

Comment: Slightly different, using date's -f option: `cat file.txt | sed "s/^.*\([0-9]\{13\}\).*/@\1/" | date -f -`

Answer (score 0):

This is similar solution but it will find a timestamp in the stream

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{13\}\)/`date -d @\1`/; s/$/"/' | bash
```